# Proving that when $f(x^0_1,x^0_2)>0$ and continuous we can find $\delta >0$ with all function values within $N_\delta (x^0_1,x^0_2)$ be positive

Tags: general-topology

For such proving question that function $y = f(x_1,x_2)$ is continuous at $(x^0_1,x^0_2)$ and when  $f(x^0_1,x^0_2)>0$ we can find $\delta >0$ that all function values within $N_\delta (x^0_1,x^0_2)$ are positive.
I started off with
$\forall \epsilon > 0,  \exists \delta: ||f(x_1,x_2)-f(x^0_1,x^0_2))|| < \epsilon s.t.||x-x^0|| < \delta$
as the law of continuity and as the question requires all function values have to be positive along the $N_\delta (x^0_1,x^0_2)$, I put $f(x^0_1,x^0_2)-\epsilon >0$. From here I am kinda lost how to go further on relating epsilon with delta...

Comment: Take $\varepsilon = f(x_0, y_0)>0$. Then $|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)| < \varepsilon$ implies $f(x,y)>0$ as well. Now continuity gives us the required $\delta$ for this.

Comment: You have the definition of continuity backwards, It is $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\|x - x^0\| < \delta \implies \|f(x) - f(x^0)\| < \epsilon$, not the other way around as you wrote. Since this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, it is true for $\epsilon = f(x^0)$, as Henno Brandsma says.